# Importing matplotlib module into a pipenv environment - vscode

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, module, pylint

Just starting to learn matplotlib and I'm getting an error when importing the module. I'm using a pipenv environment inside of vscode. I think pylint might be pointing to my global Python installation rather than my pipenv environment. If I install matplotlib to my global installation, this works.

This is the error: Unable to import 'matplotlib.pyplot'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(squares)

plt.show()
```

I've tried the solutions to questions similar to this but not seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just so people can see this solution in future. I fixed this by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and opening the select interpreter setting and changing it to the current virtual environment installation.

Hope this helps somebody!